# How to discern if an optional named parameter in dart was given?

Tags: dart

I am implementing a redux store where I treat the store as immutable. Therefore the store looks something like this:

```dart
class State {
  final String firstname;
  final String lastname;

  State(this.firstname, this.lastname);

  State.initial()
      : this.firstname = null,
        this.lastname = null;

  State copy({String firstname, String lastname}) => 
    new State(firstname ?? this.firstname, lastname ?? this.lastname);
}
```

This all works fine and I can copy the State and replace individual fields within the copy.

```dart
state.copy(firstname: "foo");
```

but now I can't set a field back to null of course.

```dart
state.copy(firstname: null);
```

doesn't work.

I also tried something like:

```dart
State copy({String firstname = this.firstname, String lastname = this.lastname}) => ...
```

but Dart does not allow non const as default values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a special marker in the file like this

```
const _noValueGiven = const Object();

class State {
  ...
  State copy({String firstName: _noValueGiven, String lastName: _noValueGiven}) {
    if (identical(firstName, _noValueGiven)) {
      firstName = this.firstName;
    }
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: Note that this will be invalid in Dart 2.0 (assigning Object to String).

You could use a sentinel string, i.e. '__notSpecified__'

Comment: Also, `const Object()` is an unsafe sentinel value becuase constants are canonicalized. Any other `const Object()` in the program will evaluate to the same object.

Comment: So far I went with this solution and it looks great and has not much boilerplate overhead. And I am actually not using it for String parameters but for Objects. For Strings I would go with "" for setting to empty and null for not present. I am not so sure about the canonicalization, I think I have to play with it more to fully understand that implication.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to distinguish whether a parameter was not provided at the call site, or it was provided with the same value as the default value.

You have to pick one value which is unlikely to be actually provided as an argument, in this case perhaps the empty string `""` (you could say that an empty string is *not* a valid name, so providing it is ignored, whereas passing in `null` is a way to unset the name).

If there is no value that is not meaningful, you have to use a sentinel of a different type, and somehow allow the function to accept that type, preferably without letting the type or sentinel value leak into the API documentation.

To do that, you can use a private sub-class to hide the implementation:

```dart
abstract class State { 
  ...
  State(String firstName, String lastName) = _State;
  State copy({String firstName, String lastName});
}
class _State implements State {
  String firstName, lastName;
  _State(this.firstName, this.lastName);
  State copy({Object firstName = 0, Object lastName = 0}) {
    if (firstName != null && firstName is! String) { 
      firstName = this.firstName;
    }
    if (lastName != null && lastName is! String) {
      lastName = this.lastName;
    }
    return new _State(firstName, lastName);
  }
}
```

This way, no user has the type that allows non-String argument, so they get warnings if they try, and your `_State.copy` code is safe for any actual argument - it ignores any non-`String`, non-`null` value.

When possible, I really recommend letting `null` mean the same as omitting the argument. It makes it much easier for everybody else to forward a call to the method. Otherwise they also need to detect whether their parameters were passed or not. In this case, I'd probably use the empty string to represent empty values instead of `null`, and let `null` be the "no argument passed" marker.

Answer (score 0):

### Solution

```
class Dog{
  final String name;
  final int age;
  Dog({this.name, this.age});
  
  Dog.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map): 
    name = map['name'] as String, age = map['age'] as int;
  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() => {'name': name, 'age': age};
  
  Dog copyWith(Map<String, dynamic> fields){
    var newObj = this.toMap();
    for (final field in fields.entries)
      newObj[field.key] = field.value;
    return Dog.fromMap(newObj);
  }
}

void main() {
  Dog buddy = Dog(name: 'Buddy', age: 12);
  Dog puppy = buddy.copyWith({'age': null});
  
  // OUTPUT=> Name: Buddy Age: null
  print('Name: ${puppy.name} Age: ${puppy.age}');
}
```